# Find Coordinate X of right triangle?

Tags: geometry

How can I find $x$ in the picture below:
[image]

This is just a simplified version to get the solution of finding $x$ because I have to program this in my application to get the desired result in image processing.

Comment: x is the first coordinate of the point above, it is 5.

Comment: @user376343 yes because we human can see, how can i solve it mathematically.

Comment: In your example, mathematically if you put a right triangle with one leg along the $x$ axis and the third point at $(a,b),$ the right angle is at $(a,0).$ That's how Cartesian coordinates work.

Comment: @DavidK Do we have any better solution for this like a formula or something

Comment: That _is_ the formula for that question. Perhaps you oversimplified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the projection of a vector to another vector. If you have vector $\vec{a}$ and vector $\vec{b}$, the projection of vector $\vec{a}$ onto the vector $\vec{b}$ is calculated by
$$
{a}_{\text{proj}} = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{| \vec{b}|}
$$ 
where $| \vec{b}|$ is the length of vector $\vec{b}$.

In your case, $\vec{a} = (5,5)$ and $\vec{b} = (1,0)$. Do you know how to calculate the dot product? I can still do it for you:
$$
{a}_{\text{proj}} = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{| \vec{b}|} = \frac{5\times 1 + 5\times 0}{1} = 5
$$

Note that this is the most general way of calculating the projection. Your particular example is so easy you can really see the answer already from the picture, without calculating anything.

Comment: in my case b = (0,0)

Comment: You're projecting on the $x$-axis. What is a vector that has the same direction as the $x$-axis? $(1,0)$ of course. You cannot project anything on $(0,0)$ because it's only a point, it doesn't represent any line.